# grep for a term only on lines that match another term

Tags: bash, grep

I want to highlight terms in grep, which I've successfully done. I also want to highlight other terms (`UP,LOWER_UP`) but only if it is on a line matching the previous term. However, I don't want to highlight the entire line.

Example input:

```
lo: blah blah UP,LOWER_UP
eth0: blah blah UP,LOWER_UP
blah0: blah blah
blah1: blah something something UP
```

Desired output (** means colour highlighted)

```
lo: blah blah UP,LOWER_UP
**eth0**: blah blah **UP,LOWER_UP**
blah0: blah blah
blah1: blah something something UP
```

My current progress (** means colour highlighted):
`UP,LOWER_UP` is highlighted on the line starting with `lo:` which I don't want.

```
lo: blah blah **UP,LOWER_UP**
**eth0**: blah blah **UP,LOWER_UP**
blah0: blah blah
blah1: blah something something UP
```

My current code:

```sh
connected_interfaces="" # we will add terms here to grep them

cd /sys/class/net || exit 1
for i in *;do
    if cat "/sys/class/net/$i/carrier" &>/dev/null; then # don't try to process invalid files
        if grep -q 1 "/sys/class/net/$i/carrier"; then
            if [[ $i != "lo" ]]; then
                if [[ $connected_interfaces == "" ]]; then
                    connected_interfaces="$i:"
                else
                    connected_interfaces="$connected_interfaces|$i:"
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
GREP_COLOR='1;32;33' ip link show | grep --color=always -E "$connected_interfaces|$" | GREP_COLOR='1;32;32' grep --color -E "UP,LOWER_UP|$"
```

I don't want to simple cut out non matching lines because I like seeing all the interfaces on a system.

Comment: Do you have GNU grep with PCRE? Try `... | grep --color=always -P '^eth0:.*\KUP,LOWER_UP|' | grep -P '^eth0(?=:)|'`

Comment: @Sundeep apparently I do (`$ grep --version => grep (GNU grep) 3.6`) but running `ip link show | grep --color=always -P '^eth0:.*\KUP,LOWER_UP|' | grep -P '^eth0(?=:)|'` results in no highlighting at all

Comment: try adding color option for the second grep as well, my grep is aliased for color so I missed that while testing